# Estimate and 95% CI for planned contrasts in R

Tags: r, anova

Here's my problem: Why do the following procedures (classical version and custom function) for planned contrasts lead to different results for the estimate and the 95%CI? Please note that I copied the custom function from this [website](https://nickmichalak.com/post/2019-02-13-testing-between-subjects-contrasts-in-r/testing-between-subjects-contrasts-in-r/).

```
#classical version
data(mtcars)
#set Helmert contrasts
cyl2<-c(-1,1,0)
cyl1<-c(-1,-1,2)
mtcars$cyl<-factor(mtcars$cyl)
contrasts(mtcars$cyl) <-cbind(c1,c2)
classical<-summary.lm(aov(disp~cyl, mtcars))

#custom function (I want to use it because it includes results for equal AND unequal variances --> if the custom function is correct, results for equal variances should be the same as in the classical example):
oneway <- function(dv, group, contrast, alpha = .05) {
  # -- arguments --
  # dv: vector of measurements (i.e., dependent variable)
  # group: vector that identifies which group the dv measurement came from
  # contrast: list of named contrasts
  # alpha: alpha level for 1 - alpha confidence level
  # -- output --
  # computes confidence interval and test statistic for a linear contrast of population means in a between-subjects design
  # returns a data.frame object
  # estimate (est), standard error (se), t-statistic (z), degrees of freedom (df), two-tailed p-value (p), and lower (lwr) and upper (upr) confidence limits at requested 1 - alpha confidence level
  # first line reports test statistics that assume variances are equal
  # second line reports test statistics that do not assume variances are equal
  
  # means, standard deviations, and sample sizes
  ms <- by(dv, group, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
  vars <- by(dv, group, var, na.rm = TRUE)
  ns <- by(dv, group, function(x) sum(!is.na(x)))
  
  # convert list of contrasts to a matrix of named contrasts by row
  contrast <- matrix(unlist(contrast), nrow = length(contrast), byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(names(contrast), NULL))
  
  # contrast estimate
  est <- contrast %*% ms
  
  # welch test statistic
  se_welch <- sqrt(contrast^2 %*% (vars / ns))
  t_welch <- est / se_welch
  
  # classic test statistic
  mse <- anova(lm(dv ~ factor(group)))$"Mean Sq"[2]
  se_classic <- sqrt(mse * (contrast^2 %*% (1 / ns)))
  t_classic <- est / se_classic
  
  # if dimensions of contrast are NULL, nummer of contrasts = 1, if not, nummer of contrasts = dimensions of contrast
  num_contrast <- ifelse(is.null(dim(contrast)), 1, dim(contrast)[1])
  df_welch <- rep(0, num_contrast)
  df_classic <- rep(0, num_contrast)
  
  # makes rows of contrasts if contrast dimensions aren't NULL
  if(is.null(dim(contrast))) contrast <- t(as.matrix(contrast))
  
  # calculating degrees of freedom for welch and classic
  for(i in 1:num_contrast) {
    df_classic[i] <- sum(ns) - length(ns)
    df_welch[i] <- sum(contrast[i, ]^2 * vars / ns)^2 / sum((contrast[i, ]^2 * vars / ns)^2 / (ns - 1))
  }
  
  # p-values
  p_welch <- 2 * (1 - pt(abs(t_welch), df_welch))
  p_classic <- 2 * (1 - pt(abs(t_classic), df_classic))
  
  # 95% confidence intervals
  lwr_welch <- est - se_welch * qt(p = 1 - (alpha / 2), df = df_welch)
  upr_welch <- est + se_welch * qt(p = 1 - (alpha / 2), df = df_welch)
  lwr_classic <- est - se_classic * qt(p = 1 - (alpha / 2), df = df_classic)
  upr_classic <- est + se_classic * qt(p = 1 - (alpha / 2), df = df_classic)
  
  # output
  data.frame(contrast = rep(rownames(contrast), times = 2),
             equal_var = rep(c("Assumed", "Not Assumed"), each = num_contrast),
             est = rep(est, times = 2),
             se = c(se_classic, se_welch),
             t = c(t_classic, t_welch),
             df = c(df_classic, df_welch),
             p = c(p_classic, p_welch),
             lwr = c(lwr_classic, lwr_welch),
             upr = c(upr_classic, upr_welch))
}

#results for mtcars with and without Welch correction:
custom<-(with(mtcars, 
      oneway(dv = disp, group= cyl, contrast = list (cyl1=c(-1,-1,2), cyl2 =c(-1,1,0)))))
```

Now results are the same for p and t for the classical and the custom version, as expected (at least when equal_var = Assumed). But why are the estimate and the 95%CIs different?

```
> custom
  contrast   equal_var       est       se         t        df            p       lwr      upr
1     cyl1     Assumed 417.74935 37.20986 11.226845 29.000000 4.487966e-12 341.64664 493.8521
2     cyl2     Assumed  78.17792 24.96113  3.131986 29.000000 3.945539e-03  27.12667 129.2292
3     cyl1 Not Assumed 417.74935 40.30748 10.364066 18.452900 3.985000e-09 333.21522 502.2835
4     cyl2 Not Assumed  78.17792 17.67543  4.422972  9.224964 1.566927e-03  38.34147 118.0144
> classical

Call:
aov(formula = disp ~ cyl, data = mtcars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-77.300 -30.586  -6.568  20.814 118.900 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  213.850      9.507  22.494  < 2e-16 ***
cyl1         69.625      6.202  11.227 4.49e-12 ***
cyl2         39.089     12.481   3.132  0.00395 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 51.63 on 29 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8377,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8265 
F-statistic: 74.83 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: 3.551e-12
```

PS: This was my best attempt to solve this problem. Alternatively, I would be happy for any ideas on how to get estimates and 95%CIs for Welch-corrected contrasts in R that would not involve relying on custom functions from blogs.